# Winforms Crystal Report - "Failed to load database information" error

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access, 64-bit, crystal-reports-2010

I have developed a small crystal reports win forms application that connects to an Access DB in the local network and shows a set of basic reports.

I used VS 2010 for this.

I used the 'DAO' connectivity method to access the DB in the VS 2010 Database expert option (Yes, Its all done in the GUI). It works all fine and dandy in my 32 bit dev machine and an Win XP VM machine that i tested it on.

However, I setup the reports on a Win 7 64bit PC and I get this error.
[image: Error screen shot]

These are the installations I made on the 64bit Win 7 PC:

- SAP Crystal Reports runtime engine for .NET Fx 4 (64-bit)
- .NET Framework 4 Client profile (x86 & x64)

What I have read till now is that the 64 bit CR runtime engine is ot shipped with the dll (crdb_dao.dll) which is available in 32 bit version.

Any suggestions... Any workarounds?

Appreciate your help :-)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### It's all about bitness

With Access databases, you have to be careful about the bitness of your application:

- There is not standard 64 bit driver for `.mdb` files (there is one by default in Windows for 32 bits though).
- To be able to access `.mdb` and `.accdb` databases from a 64 bit application, you must have MSOffice 64 bit or Access 64 bit or the [Access Database Engine](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) drivers for 64 bit.
  If you have MSOffice or Access 2007/2010/2013 32 bit installed on that machine, you won't be able to install the 64 bit driver, you can't mix and match 32 bit and 64 bit Office components.

#### To solve your issue

- If you are using `.mdb` Access files, simply compile for 32 bits explicitly (not AnyCPU since it will try to launch your app as 64 bit in a 64 OS).
- If you are using `.accdb` Access files, match the bitness of Office/Access installed on the user machine, or, if Office isn't there, install the [Access Database Engine](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) driver.
- In any case, if your application is to be deployed in mixed 32 / 64 bit environments, you will need to compile explicitly for each and install the right version according to the bitness of the [Access Database Engine](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) or MSOffice installed on the user's machine.

Note: just to clarify, if MSOffice 2007/2010/2013 is already installed on the user's machine, there is no need to install the Access Database Engine.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I would like to mention that due to MS licensing issues I have installed Access 2007 and The rest of the apps like Excel etc via Office 2010.

Therefore, I tried compiling the exe in 32 bit and executed it. I got the following error in form load itself:

**Fault bucket 50, type 5
Event Name: CLR20r3
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: ho timesheet reports.exe
P2: 1.0.0.0
P3: 50a22541
P4: CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
P5: 13.0.2000.0
P6: 4feae845
P7: 32d
P8: 7
P9: System.TypeInitialization
P10:**

Comment: Could you please help me out on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44300956/crystal-report-is-not-opening-for-64-bit-machines

Answer (score 3):

I had to install the CR Runtime engine for 32 bit as well. Now its working smooth :-)!

Thanks alot :)!

Comment: Could you please specify in detail what you did, I am really stuck here. Thanks in advance.