# Error with Crystal Report

Tags: .net, vb.net, crystal-reports

While trying to print an Invoice using Crystal Reports I get this error:

[image]

This is my code:

```
Private Sub btn_print_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_print.Click
    Dim str As String = My.Settings.DatabaseNameConnectionString
    Dim con As New SqlConnection(str)
    Dim com As String = "select Name,SUM(Total),SUM(Quantity),SUM(Discount),SUM(Tax) from purchase group by Name"
    Dim adpt As New SqlDataAdapter(com, con)
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    adpt.Fill(ds, "purchase")
    cr1.SetDataSource(dgv_purchase.DataSource)
    purchaseReport.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cr1
    purchaseReport.CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
    purchaseReport.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

As per OP's comment:

Query runs OK in SSMS and the error still occurs when changing `cr1.SetDataSource(dgv_purchase.DataSource)` to `cr1.SetDataSource(ds.Tables(0))`

Comment: It's difficult to tell where the error is but after a quick look I did find [this](https://forums.asp.net/t/1178464.aspx)

Comment: There is also an SO link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356765/winforms-crystal-report-failed-to-load-database-information-error). It could be you need to install something.

Comment: Ok.Let me try...

Comment: Thank you very much